Vuetify v-dialog-sheet with rounded corners
How do you implement round corners of the dialog of the v-bottom-sheet? style="border-radius:20px;" make rounded overlay not the dialog.
<v-bottom-sheet style="border-radius:20px;"  v-model="sheet" inset>
  <v-sheet class="text-center">
    <h1 style="color:red;">Header</h1>
    <br>
  </v-sheet>
</v-bottom-sheet>


Did you try changing the SASS variable

I hope you meant that.
    <v-bottom-sheet v-model="sheet" inset>
      <v-sheet style="border-radius: 20px" class="text-center">
        <h1 style="color: red">Header</h1>
        <br />
      </v-sheet>
    </v-bottom-sheet>

